# CSS - is there a tool that automatically groups common shared styles between selectors?

Tags: css

I usually write all the CSS per each class or id, and at the end I group them together per shared styles.

```
.first {width:100px; height:35px}
.second {width:100px;}
```

Is there a tool that groups them automatically, to produce this result?

```
.first, .second {width:100px;}
.first{height:35px;}
```

Comment: Many CSS minifiers can do this. Just Google for it until you find one that works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question is that you want to do less job on CSS. Actually, there's a javascript library that enables you to write less CSS called [cssless](http://lesscss.org/). There you can declare constants, functions, and write nested CSS which is great, and alot more.

Check out at [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: It sounds like the OP is asking for tools that convert existing CSS files though.

Comment: Yeah as Paul said, i need a tool to convert the existing CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know of any such tool. (Good question though, maybe someone else will.)

It would be great, but I imagine it would be very complicated to write. For example, what if the original CSS looked like this?

```
.first {width:100px; height:35px}
.second {width:150px;}
.second {width:100px;}
```

The tool would presumably change it to:

```
.first, .second {width:100px;}
.first{height:35px;}
.second {width:150px;}
```

Now `.second` is 150 pixels wide instead of 100. (Obviously, this is a bit of an unlikely edge case.)

Comment: mmm, could be but yeah i think it's a bit over. Could be set to take the first selector and the style, then set the second one aside.

Comment: It's simple. The "width: 150px" is never used, so the tool should delete it at all.